# jQuery ujs inside of a jquery modal not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I have mostly all of my forms for different controllers in a jquery dialog modal box, and the problem i'm running into is that when those modals are loaded, the ujs links(data-remote, data-confirm, etc) are completely ignored by jquery. I'm thinking that when those partials are getting loaded through ajax, that the events aren't bubbling up to include those new links that are added to the dom by ajax. Has anyone run into this? I can't seem to figure out a way around it. I can post some code if this wasn't very clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I fixed it with this, using a custom jquery ui dialog box I can now do custom confirms ontop of remote true links

```
var myCustomConfirmBox;
$.rails.allowAction = function(element) {
  var answer, callback, message;
  message = element.data("confirm");
  answer = false;
  callback = void 0;
  if (!message) {
    return true;
  }
  if ($.rails.fire(element, "confirm")) {
    myCustomConfirmBox(message, element);
  }
  return false;
};
myCustomConfirmBox = function(message, callback) {
  $("#dialog-confirm .content").html(message);
  return $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 180,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
    Continue: function() {
      $.rails.handleRemote(callback);
      return $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      return $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If markup is being added dynamically the events are only going to work if you make use of event delegation.

There's a pretty good writeup on the basics of event delegation in jQuery here - http://jqueryfordesigners.com/simple-use-of-event-delegation/.  Basically you'll want to switch handlers created through `bind` to use `on`.

Comment: The default rails functionality for :remote => true and data-confirm are what aren't working in links that are generated by ajax. When I have a :data => {:confirm => "sure?"} with :remote => true, it'll ask the confirm question, hitting continue does a page refresh and not the remote call.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the init of your ujs to the open callback on the dialog.

Comment: There is no jquery_ujs initing going on, just including it in the asset pipeline puts it into the document. Do you mean actually adding a new    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I try the the method by Magicmarkker,
just add the versioned js import code in the modal view page, and it works, cheers!

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
```